# FB.ui, feed dialog, add default message

Tags: facebook, web

Good evening! I'm working on a Facebook integrated website and want to share a picture along with a default message, preferably using Facebooks own dialogs and not posting directly via the Graph API.

Is it possible to add a proposed message to the dialog? And can i get the picture to take up more space?

Current code:

```
function showCustomShare(){
    FB.ui({
      appId: '0000000000',
      display: "popup",
      method: "feed",
      name: "",
      link:"",
      caption:"",
      description: "",
      picture: "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8496/8278663662_76d408c166_h.jpg",
    }, function(response){});
```

Result:

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

The feed dialog is deprecated and has been replaced with the share dialog.

There is no longer a way to add a proposed message.

Deprecation notice: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.0

New share dialog (allowed parameters at the bottom of the page):
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

Comment: Feed dialog is not deprecated, only v2.0 is outdated. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.5

Answer (score 0):

```
function shareOverrideOGMeta(overrideLink, overrideTitle, overrideDescription, overrideImage)
{
    FB.ui({
        method: 'share_open_graph',
        action_type: 'og.shares',
        action_properties: JSON.stringify({
            object: {
                'og:url': overrideLink,
                'og:title': overrideTitle,
                'og:description': overrideDescription,
                'og:image': overrideImage
            }
        })
    },
    function (response) {
    // Action after response
    });
}

    shareOverrideOGMeta(window.location.href,title, description,image);
```